# My Dell Laptop is not connecting with wifi router

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, laptop, router

One of my Dell laptop is not connecting with wifi network, once i troubleshot, then it show message to restart your WIFI router, but after restarting the router its not connecting.

Earlier, this laptop was connecting perfectly with WIFI. My Dell laptop configuration is Windows 7 OS and  processor is Core i5.

I don't think the problem is related to WIFI router, because my another laptop and mobile device is connecting successfully with WIFI.

Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: What access point and which chipset has your laptop wifi ? There exist some incompatibilities.

Comment: How far away are you? Does this issue occur when close to the router? Also, is there a problem when hard wired?

Comment: @DaveRook, If i used wired with modem then its connecting correctly.

Comment: And does it kick in depending on distance from router? Put the laptop next to it, reboot and see if it works please.

Comment: I have done all steps and its not too far from router, earlier this problem come but when i restart the router then its resolve but this time its not connecting any time.

Comment: Using System Restore in Windows 7, have you tried restoring to a date previous to this problem occurring?

Comment: Ah. This sounds like a DNS issue then. Can you check to see if you're on a static or dynamic IP address please

Comment: its use dynamic IP address.

Comment: To me it looks like you've told your windows to ignore that specific wifi router. Dive into the network settings, it is in it somewhere (I'm not at home right now).

Comment: Have you checked if your DCHP is set up properly on your laptop? Also: Does it work via ethernet or on another wireless network?

Answer (score 0):

its my last night problem look at [here](https://superuser.com/questions/819933/cant-connect-to-any-wireless-network)

what exactly happens when you try to connect

and what exactly you have done tease days like installing new programs new drivers updates or etc ... ?

the simple way to solve this is to remove driver and uninstall it from device manager (mark uninstall driver) and let windows install it with its own driver it will work if your wifi channel be less than 12

maybe your wireless channel goes to 12 ,13 or 14 there are hard ways to access these channels but you can go to your modem panel under wireless settings change channel to 1 to 11 or if you set it on automatic set your country to USA

if you cant change wifi channel you should to try so much things

- first of all try to go device manager > properties of your wifi adapter >advanced >location>put it on JP or EU
- sometimes with upgrading wifi driver you can access wifi channels 12 to 14 try [this too](https://superuser.com/questions/819933/cant-connect-to-any-wireless-network)
- you may need to change your location in windows to JP or EU but its a week way
- you can add location to your wifi adapter from registry like [here](https://superuser.com/questions/815925/connect-nexus-5-and-vostro-3300-to-wireless-channel-13)

**i suggest you to know what channel your modem is and then try to do any thing you can use android apps like (wifi Analyzer) or another**

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: @davidpostill it was the actual ways that workes for me and then end of question so i think it could be the right answer, am i wrong?