# connect nexus 5 and vostro 3300 to wireless channel 13

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point, nexus-5

i have dell vostro 3300 and nexus 5 in my univercity i cant connect to nearly wifi it is on channel 13
what can i do ? my laptop can access channel 13 but my new windows wifi location just have USA what to do ?
 (i cant change wifi channel )

------------laptop driver (dw1520 wireless-n half-mini card)

-solved part 1 (vostro 3300 solved )
after trying so many things i went to registry in
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0000\Ndi\params\Country\enum
add new value name EU value EU 
then i went back to device manager in wifi location and now i have EU after selecting it now i can see channel 12 and 13

**-i still need access wifi channel 13 on my nexus 5 (not rooted** if it was rooted i can change location in system>etc>wifi> field ccard )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved part 1 (vostro 3300 solved ) after trying so many things i went to registry in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0000\Ndi\params\Country\enum add new value name EU value EU then i went back to device manager in wifi location and now i have EU after selecting it now i can see channel 12 and 13