# Can't connect to any wireless network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, drivers, windows-8.1, bios

Today I connected to my friend's wifi and tried to troubleshooting my old problem

[Low ram in windows 8.1 update](https://superuser.com/questions/816746/low-ram-in-windows-8-1-update)

For the last trick I went for bios update and hdd regenerator. I have vostro 3300 and update it to a10 and a12 from dell.com and my product number and nothing's wrong I even restart 2 or 3 times and everything was fine.

After I came home I try to connect to my home wifi and windows 8.1 updated says that (cannot connect to the network).

I almost try everything like

1. driver update or downgrade
2. windows repair
3. normal nod32 scan
4. switch to local account
5. uninstalling hdd regenerator, dell wifi controller, some other programs
6. uninstall and reinstall wifi driver
7. disabling Bluetooth driver
8. disabling virtual box network adapter and remove it from wifi
9. test in safe mode
10. and know I'm scanning under safe mode with nod 32 (eset)

Suggest me what to do.

**UPDATE**

**I can see the wifi's but it has low rate of refresh**.

**I can put wifi pass and windows try to connect but it ends on authentication.**

**I put the correct password and I'm 100% sure.**

**I test it with my phone wifi it cannot connect to my phone wifi either so it's not my modem**

**exact errors:**

- most of the time after I put password it says verifying and connecting and then says can't connect to this network
- sometimes it shows connecting and even connected and wifi signal is full (it is half always) and then it disconnects
- after try to reconnect again it shows checking network requirements and then show can't connect to this network

I try to forget it and doing the same things showing the same result.

Comment: Can you be more specific about not being able to connect? Does it see the SSID, then fail? Are you 100% sure the radio is on, too many laptops these days have a weird switch or hotkey to toggle wifi radio.

Comment: i posted an update so other no need to read comments thanks for your attention

Comment: If you can't connect with your computer AND phone then it DOES point up-stream, it could be your 'modem' (I suspect router). Could you connect to your home network before you went over to your friends?

Comment: i said that cannot connect to my phone ether(it means that i cant connect to my phone hot spot and cant connect to my modem ) sadly i was in a trip like 2 weak and i forced to change my windows and everything but modem is fine i can connect to it with my phone and other ones phones and laptops

Comment: If it's a Dell, you need to use the Dell drivers, use the Dell wireless utility that works with your hardware, and use that Dell Wireless Utility to connect to your wireless access point. Do not use the Windows built in wireless feature

Comment: i forced to update it(i needed to connect to channel 13) this driver is signed and same name as mine mine was for 2009 and its 2012 but i will re install and tell you whats happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

uninstalling the best driver (channel 13 support) [DW1520 Wireless-N Half-mini ] and installing windows [Broadcom 802.11n Network Adapter ] solved my problem special thanks to   ChrisinNL [https://superuser.com/users/373162/chrisinnl]